# strange mkdir behaviour in php

Tags: php, mkdir

i have a very strange problem with mkdir()
i am creating a chunk uploader with resumable js sometimes it seems to work fine but sometimes it gives me an exception (i am working with laravel 5.3) that tottaly baffles my understanding this code:

```
if(!is_dir($path)){
     mkdir($path,0777);
     }
```

even if the conditional statement above is supplied with a directory path that exists mkdir still executes resulting to a mkdir() file exists error i am really stuck with this any help would be appreciated

even worse now the error is comming from laravels core files... i think this might be a php bug

in Filesystem.php line 419

at HandleExceptions->handleError('2', 'mkdir(): File exists', 'C:\wamp64\www\XXXX\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Filesystem\Filesystem.php', '419'

Comment: Are you sure `$path` only contains a diirectory path and does not include a filename as well?

Comment: use @mkdir($path,0777)

Comment: @PradyutManna that won't fix the problem. It will just hide it.

Comment: @PradyutManna just hiding your sorrows wont make them go away.

Comment: It possibly fails because $path is not a directory but a file of different type, so it will not be catched by is_dir(). Use [file_exists()](https://secure.php.net/manual/de/function.file-exists.php).

Comment: @RiggsFolly i have checked the code and it is a directory

Comment: Post error, please.

Comment: @GardenApple look at the edit above

Comment: "File exists".  You have filename in $path and is_dir($path) return false. Because isset file is not folder.